# Is this an actual, named, stitch?

Tags: sewing, cross-stitch

Is this an actual stitch, or am I just hacking together a knot and a running stitch?

1. Thread needle through the fabric
2. Run the needle through the previous stitch (between the fabric and previous loop's thread)
3. Loop the needle around the thread coming out of the fabric, from step 1, twice to create a knot
4. Pull the knot tight and repeat the steps a few millimeters away, in a line.

(MS Painted graphic for reference)

[image: Image of described stitch, created in MS Paint]

Comment: It looks like the famous Dave Matney stitch.  :-)

Comment: Weird, who named a stitch after me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result looks like a "bullion stitch" or a "french knot" and there's a quicker way to get the same result.

For the bullion stitch you wrap the thread around the needle before stitching a short length forward. Ideally the spiral of the wrapped thread is just as long as the stitch length. This stitch is used for things like flower petals or other strongly textured embroidery.

**The bullion stitch**: ([image source](https://pumora.com/bullion-stitch-clover-flower-embroidery-tutorial/), [further tutorial](https://sewguide.com/make-embroidery-flowers/))
[image]

For the french knot you also wrap the thread around the needle, but you stitch back into the same hole where the needle came out or very, very close next to it. The result is a small, raised knot that is also used for floral embroidery or just texture in general.

**The french knot**: ([image source](https://www.stitchdoodles.com/hand-embroidery-stitch-guide/))
[image]

Comment: I think this is probably the closest... I'm misusing a cross-stitching stitch.